# Maximum length of subset such that all elements are coprime

Tags: number-theory

Given an array, we have to find the length of maximum subset such that all elements of that subset are coprime. That is for $a[i],a[j]$ belonging to subset $\gcd(a[i],a[j]) = 1$ for all distinct $i,j$.

Comment: I can't tell exactly what you're asking about here, but to me this sounds more like a coding question than a mathematics question.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a $O(n^2)$ way to do it, and I'm pretty sure that's optimal. First, find out which pairs of numbers are coprime. Assuming your numbers are bounded, this takes constant time for each pair with the Euclidean algorithm. Now you have a graph, and the problem is to find the size of the largest connected component. Depth first search will do that for you.